# How do i change the value of a checkboxed item in react? (changing one value in sql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

First of all, sorry if the title is worded badly, i wasn't sure how to state it any better.
So my problem is that i have a database in mysql with different Bikes (imagine i have two bikes from diamond, one bike from scott etc) which in my database are stored on different physical locations with the tag FK_LocationID.

And i want to be able to "move" these bikes from one location to another by checking the bikes i want to move and selecting the location i want to move them two by picking from a dropdown (not neccessary). Tldr i want to change the FK_LocationID of checkboxed bikes. I have 5 arrays of bikes (there are 5 different locations, Santa Ana being locationID number 1)

```
export default class Locations extends Component {
  bikes1 = [];
  bikes2 = [];
  bikes3 = [];
  bikes4 = [];
  bikes5 = [];
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <Card title="Locations">
          <Row>
            <Column>
              <p>1 - Haugastøl</p> // i have 5 of these
              <List>
                {this.bikes1.map(bike1 => (
                  <List.Item key={bike1.BikeID}>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={bike1.checked} onChange={e 
         => bike1.checked = e.target.checked}/> {bike1.BikeID} - {bike1.Brand}
                  </List.Item>
                ))}
              </List>

          <select id="Location" value={this.FK_LocationID} onChange={e => (this.FK_LocationID= e.target.value)}>
            <option value={0}>Choose location..</option>
            <option value={1}>Haugastøl</option>
            <option value={2}>Finse </option>
            <option value={3}>Flåm </option>
            <option value={4}>Voss </option>
            <option value={5}>Myrdal </option>
          </select>



  mounted() {
    locationService.getBikesLocation1(bikes1 => { // 5 of these aswell
      for(let bike of bikes1) bike.checked = false;
      this.bikes1 = bikes1;
    }); 
    locationService.getBikesLocation2(bikes2 => {
      for(let bike of bikes2) bike.checked = false;
      this.bikes2 = bikes2;
    });
```

Basically ive made a dropdown, checkboxes and now im not sure how to actually change the FK_LocationID of the checked items. I would really appreciate any help here, im new to React and also javascript really.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need state. What you could/should do is put the check boxes in a form or json object, and post it to your backend, and from there make the changes in your db. Local state won't help make changes to the back end, and since you mentioned sql I am assuming that you have one. If I'm wrong sorry, but just realize  that local state is not persistent so when you restart your app you will need to redo the changes.

Comment: Yes, thank you thats what im trying to do! :) But im not sure how to code it, could you clarify this? Also im trying to make this function change the db values onevent if that was onclear.

Comment: Well I'm not going to  code the whole thing for you, it would be too hard without knowing anything about your backend or db. Here are the steps in order of how I would do it so you can research them on your own. 1: make a form with the check boxes you need. 2: post that form to your back end 3: update your db with those values.

Comment: Thank you, im not sure how but i am going to try this :)!

Comment: Which part are you unsure of making a form, posting to server, or the backend stuff?

Comment: Honestly both making the form and the posting to server.. this is my server:https://imgur.com/a/zw766Rj , but the only value that needs to change is the FK_Location so i was hoping to be able to make a simple function that selected the checked bikes from bikes1- bikes5 and changed them to the selected location from the dropdown, but this might not be as simple as i thought.